Keycloak SSO unauthenticated redirection
Heyo,
I'm looking for a way to configure keycloak so that when unauthenticated, it returns to my login page. At the moment SSO with facebook works, but when I'm in the facebook page where it asks to proceed with the login or cancel, and I click on the cancel button, I'm redirected to the keycloak login page instead.
It's in a kubernetes environment, and my client redirect url is set to my app page as well. I'm probably overlooking something really silly.
Thanks in advance
What I've tried is to configure the redirect url in my keycloak client to my login page, I've also tried to configuring the OAuth redirect in facebook developer portal to my login page, but all of them seem to result in going back to my keycloak page when canceling the SSO authentication process.
What I expect is when I click on the cancel button to go into https://www.example.com/login


